# Creating 3D data structure of objects in c++, how to initliaze it properly

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I am creating a program that will help manage a Warehouse that contains a specific item.
I want to be able to store the items that I have at a warehouse at a certain time so I thought of creating a 3D vector of a type item.

is there any way to initialize it efficiently ? as I understand that when I'm using vector and want to reserve size for it, it will have to create items with the default constructor and place them there, but in reality, I am going to fill this with "real" items so I believe it's inefficient to create dummy items.

the program needs to be able to load and unload new items at any given point, and the dimensions of the warehouse are unknown at compilation time as I get it from a file while running the program.

maybe it's better using a pointer to an item?

Comment: I think it's better to have a 3d-location object, call it `Point3D`, and use that as a key in a `map<Point3D, Item>` (or a `map<Point3D, Item*>` if you want another container to be the owner of the `Item`s.

Comment: Have you implemented something that runs slow? Or is there any other reason to believe that pre-initializing them would make it notably slow?
If not, do not prematurely optimize. Simply initialize them.

Comment: @Aziuth it isn't slow at the moment but for practice purposes and efficiency, I do love to know if there is a way.
JohnFillea i will think about it but i think it's going to be pain to start move things in the warehouse with this implementation...further more keep track of

Comment: If you call `reserve` it will allocate the memory but will not initialize anything. But as @Aziuth says premature optimization  ...

Comment: Another thing I thought about - your warehouse, is it mostly empty? If so, that would be a property that one calls `sparse`. There are certain methods storing sparse data, for example types of sparse matrices, which could be elevated to the third dimension. You might be interested in reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix . In any way, we are talking a bit about something we don't know the conditions for - you should state an example, for how the warehouse looks  and what actions are typically performed on it. Also how it is initially filled.

Comment: Thanks for replys, but what if i do look to reserve each vector a space and not initialize a new object in it yet? say i want to be able to use size function and capacity to get the actual size and capacity, if i init dummy objects size would be equals to capacity...